# PostGIS: minimum distance path between polygons, constrained by a mask polygon

Tags: postgis

I need to find the shortest path between two polygons (**source** and **target**), but where the possible paths are constrained by a third (**mask**) polygon.  I am currently using ST_ShortestLine on my **source** and **target** polygons, then checking if the result lies within the **mask** polygon and flagging the resulting line as 'invalid' for manual followup if not.  But I'd like to fully automate the process.

I can see how I could theoretically do this in a GIS that supports cost-distance calculations - convert the **mask** polygon to a raster and run a lowest-cost function between the **source** and **target**.

But I can see no way of doing this in PostGIS - either using vector or raster functions.

I am running the SQL via ruby scripts, so have the option of scripting as part of the solution.

Suggestions?

Comment: Triangulate many points inside other polygon and compute path. More points,  better result

Comment: OK - get the concept I think.  Can't see a way of generating a triangle grid, but something like: Create a grid: ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(ST_SquareGrid)), then use pgRouting to find the shortest route?

Comment: Perhaps, but simplify line after, because you'll get Manhattan shortest distance,  which is always  longer.  Suggest using Chaikin smoothing algorithm

Comment: FYI https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/inside-postgis-calculating-distance

Comment: Reduce each polygon to its `ST_Intersection()` with the mask shape, then find the `ST_ShortestLine()` between those. It won't use the index so I'd keep your current two-step process, where you just grab the `ST_ShortestLine()` between unprocessed inputs, then only use the thing with `ST_Intersection()` to correct those that weren't `ST_Within()` the mask in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce each polygon to its `ST_Intersection()` with the mask shape, then find the `ST_ShortestLine()` between those. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/sWtZkHbI)

```
select st_shortestline(st_intersection(m.geom,a.geom),
                       st_intersection(m.geom,b.geom))
from __test.generated_shapes a 
join __test.generated_shapes b 
  on a.n=25 and b.n=29
cross join __test.mask m;
```

[image]

It won't use the index so I'd keep your current two-step process, where you just grab the `ST_ShortestLine()` between unprocessed inputs, then only use the thing with `ST_Intersection()` to correct those that weren't `ST_Within()` the mask in the first step.